# DDD domain identifier implementation should be ValueObject?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, value-object

In DDD we defined domain's identifier as ValueObject. [Regard here](https://www.mirkosertic.de/blog/2013/04/domain-driven-design-example/)

How ever in last project I implement those ID like so

```
public struct UserID {
    public readonly string GUID;
}

public struct UserAggregateRoot {
    public readonly UserID userID;
}
```

As it a ValueObject, However in most projects I've saw don't really rely on struct like this, instead they use string directly.

```
public struct UserAggregateRoot {
    public readonly string userID;
}
```

What difference, benefit and dangerous using each one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the use of ValueObjects goes, there is no difference between your UserID struct and the plain string version. Primitive datatypes (int, string, etc.) are just as valid as ValueObject as structs designed to be ValueObjects.

The use of a custom struct has the disadvantage that the number of classes/structs in your project increases quite a bit and you have to know where to create which struct out of the primitive data that you receive.

The use of a custom struct also has some advantages:

- Not directly relevant to your identifier example, but a struct can have multiple members, thus forming a more complex ValueObject
- It can be easier to change the underlying representation (for example, if you want to use a real GUID class instead of a string in your UserID)
- If becomes harder to make mistakes in what gets passed to another function. For example, if a function takes both a UserID and an Address, it is impossible to pass them in the wrong order if they are both structs, but an easy mistake if they both are strings.

Comment: Last point is, IMO, the most important. Type safety is the primary thing you expect when wrapping an ID into its own VO type.

Answer (score 1):

> What difference, benefit and dangerous using each one?

In general, this anti-pattern is referred to a `Primitive Obsession`.  There's a fair bit of good material about it available on line

- [Jimmy Bogard](http://grabbagoft.blogspot.com/2007/12/dealing-with-primitive-obsession.html)
- [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling/)
- [James Shore](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/PrimitiveObsession.html)
- [Chris Wheeler](http://chriswheeler.blogspot.com/2005/05/my-favourite-smells.html)

There's extra cognitive load when dealing with primitives; primitives have their own invariants, which don't usually line up with your domain.  For example, GUIDs are 128 bits of data in length, but `string` can be longer or shorter than that.  Concatenating to `string` together makes sense, but that's not a useful operation for GUID.

What does it mean to take a substring of a GUID?

By advertising that the underlying in memory representation of the data is a `string`, you are giving your consumers the opportunity to [couple their code](https://xkcd.com/1172/) to that decision, which adds friction if you want to change it later.

Put another way, the decision to use a `string` as your in memory representation of an identifier is one that can be [captured in a module](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/), reducing the cost of changing it later.

There *are* cases where the extra level of indirection is a problem; it shows up in graphics programming and the like, where the manipulation of the underlying data structures is the point, and requiring extra redirection within the inner loop is death to performance.  If you need to do some bulk operation on a billion identifiers, then you may well want access to the raw bytes, rather than some perfect "domain abstraction".